# Broadcasting From An USB Sound Card With PiFmRds Isn't Working

Tags: pi-2, raspberry-pi-os, pifm

I am using PiFmRds on my raspberry pi 3a+ (https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds), and I am trying to live broadcast with a mic and a USB sound card. The command is:

sudo arecord -fS16_LE -r 44100 -Dplughw:1,0 -c 2 -  | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio -

When I run it, though, I get this error:
[image]

What can I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Open terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Then. go to the line:

```
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
```

And replace 'on' with 'off':

```
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=off
```

Then reboot. The only catch is, tho, that your headphone jack won't work anymore. But whateva.
Also, if you are having problems with pifm on a newer pi (I had problems on my pi 3), try https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds