# Broadcasting With PiFm Isn't Working on My Pi 3A+

Tags: pi-2, raspberry-pi-os, pifm

I am trying to broadcast audio from my raspberry pi with pifm. However, it isn't working.

When I run 'sudo ./pifm sound.wav 100.0' nothing comes through on my fm radio, and also, afer about 2 or 3 seconds the terminal says 'exiting', and exits.

The same happens when I run 'sox -t mp3 ribo.mp3 -t wav -r 22050 -c 1 - | sudo ./pifm - 100.1'.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this epic PiFM!
https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds

Also, if you aare having mic problems check this out:
[Broadcasting From An USB Sound Card With PiFmRds Isn't Working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/127379/broadcasting-from-an-usb-sound-card-with-pifmrds-isnt-working)

To be honest, you might have to do it if PiFM still isn't working. My PiFM works when I have that (what it says in that question) set up, and I don't have patience to test it without that.